# Neo4j Spring Data example missing annotation @Indexed

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, neo4j, spring-data

Trying to run the neo4j spring data example on http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And

```
@NodeEntity
public class Movie {

  @GraphId Long id;

  @Indexed(type = FULLTEXT, indexName = "search")
  String title;

  Person director;

  @RelatedTo(type="ACTS_IN", direction = INCOMING)
  Set<Person> actors;

  @RelatedToVia(type = "RATED")
  Iterable<Rating> ratings;

  @Query("start movie=node({self}) match 
          movie-->genre<--similar return similar")
  Iterable<Movie> similarMovies;
}
```

but the `@Indexed(type = FULLTEXT, indexName = "search")` does not seem to exist in  `<artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>`
Do I have to add anything else to the pom ? or is this deprecated and if so how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Indexed` was present in SDN 3, but not anymore in SDN 4. You have to manage indices and constraints yourself, using [Cypher queries](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/#cypher-schema).

Shameless plug: you can use [Liquigraph](http://www.liquigraph.org) to manage your migrations.

Comment: damm they should correct the example then ... thank you